# Programming on Flash Drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I've always had separate setups on several different computers for coding, such as IDEs. I've always synced code files on dropbox when I needed to access them on a different machine. Now, I'm wondering if it would be plausible, as in not have a heavy hit on productivity, to simply install a linux distro onto a flash drive with some persistence, and just use the flash instead, freeing up more space for the Windows partitions on all of these computers.

Would this slow my productivity at all? If so, is it minor where I won't really notice it or will it be a major difference?

Comment: Seems that some people are voting to close this as being opinion based. Although there is an element of opinion, my answer is primarily fact based not opinion.

Comment: Curious, why aren't you using a source control system like git?

Comment: Because several of the computers are laptops and are rarely connected to the internet. I use a smartphone to tether internet and use that to sync dropbox. On some occasions I am able to connect them to a WiFi network. I considered switching to git, but instead I through that idea aside, as can be seen by me asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a USB3 interface and a good flash drive it might be just about acceptable.

Better would be a direct SD/microSD card interface with a Class 10 card but make sure you get a good quality named brand both for the speed and reliability.

You should note that flash drives are not high-reliability options though and they do regularly fail.

Comment: Thank's for the quick response. Unfortunately, only one of the computers I use has a built in SD card reader, so I would still have to use a card reader with a USB adapter. Would this still be a better option then a regular flash drive? The reader USB adapter is 3.0, and I do have available ports on all of the devices.

Comment: @VincentCampbell You really would need to perform benchmarks to see if its an acceptable solution yourself.

Comment: As long as you get a good, USB3 pen then you'd probably find it OK as long as you don't expect too much from it. But a pen drive will never be as fast nor as reliable as a decent SD and an SD will never be as fast or reliable as an SSD. An external USB3 SSD would most likely be as fast as an HDD.

Answer (score 0):

USB HDDs are really small nowadays, they have higher capacity than flash drives, are more reliable and often faster.

The single-point-of-failure issues still applies though. Regular back-ups are a must for your setup.

Comment: I didn't think this deserved a downvote. However, it didn't really answer the question, would probably have been better as a comment. Still, you are correct in essence. And absolutely correct about backups.